# How is back button on navigation bar implemented in AOSP code?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to understand what happens when you press the back button. how does the system manipulate the back stack? From where does it get the window handle to the top window?
I have looked into the `PhoneWindowManager.java`, but couldn't find what I am looking for. Has anybody seen this code earlier?

Answer (score 1):

What you are refering to as the "back button in the action bar" is called the "up button". The difference between the two is well explained in that article from the documentation: [Navigation with Back and Up](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).

In short:

- The Up button is used to navigate within an app based on the hierarchical relationships between screens.
- The system Back button is used to navigate, in reverse chronological order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between screens, rather than the app's hierarchy.

Difference is well market for instance when you navigate to an app from another app. E.g.: you are accessing an application's Google Play screen from a link in your mailbox. Once in Google Play:

- Up will take you to Google Play's home for applications
- Back will take you back to the GMail application

Comment: I want to know how does Android handle the system Back button. How do you actually get to the previos activity on the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will take you back, as like the back button would:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) says that the Back button simply ends the current activity. No back stack manipulation is needed.

At a deeper level, Android does maintain a stack of activities inside of a [Task](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), and it can determine which activity to show next when the top activity finishes. But those mechanisms live in native code and are probably beyond the scope of what you're trying to do. As far as I know, the best you can do from Java is to use [RunningTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html) (source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/ActivityManager.java#410)), which will expose the "base" and "top" activities in the current Task.

If you're trying to implement complex app navigation, there are [a number of flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) that you can use to control the way in which activities are placed on the stack.